# Phone uses another media screen query

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have almost all queries for every phone. (I think atleast)

Example Iphone 6/7/8 (375x667), but uses:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 640px) and (min-device-width: 360px){
   #sidebar {
       min-width: 360px;
       max-width: 360px;
       margin-right: -360px !important;
   }
}
```

My full sidebar responsive media queries:
https://jsfiddle.net/aw5ty84a/6/

Cant add all queries here.
But the problem is the phone uses too small phone resolution or iPhone 5 uses too big resolution queries.

Answer (score 0):

The queries are set by min & max pixel width so the iPhone 6 for example will only pick up the first media query relevant in the code, while ignoring any after (ignoring the correct one).

There may be a way with JS to target by specific device but you can't do so with CSS since the media queries are simply based on min/max pixel width.

You would need to change your width from exact pixels to something like percentages and use a more broad based pixel range like mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally you don't want to have a single media query for each phone size. The smallest screen size existent is 320px, so that's the smallest you want.

I like to have around 4 - 6 sizes of media queries, like XL, L, M, S and XS. XL could have max-width 1200px, L max-width 940px, and so on. This will improve your organization and code readability. Each project is different though - sometimes you may not need the XL, but may need a XXS, for instance.

Take the [Bootstrap approach](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/) to media queries breakpoints as an example. Note that these values are what Bootstrap uses, you can come up with yours to what is most appropriate for your project;

```
// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

If there is a very specific scenario where you find a bug at a specific breakpoint you can add that media query, but if you're coding clean this usually will not happen.

Good luck!